# Upload mp3 to Server PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a small mp3 through a simple html form using PHP.

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>


<form action="upload_mp3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="mp3" />

<input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php 

$mp3 = ($_FILES['mp3']['name']);

$target = "mp3/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['mp3']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mp3']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {  header("Status: 200"); } 
 else
 { echo "no";}

?>
```

Does anything look wrong with the code. Also could it be that my temp file isn't writable? If so can I get some instructions on how to make it writable.

Thanks!

Comment: The enctype is a form attribute

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your form tag has the `enctype=multipart/form-data` attribute set:

```
<form action="upload_mp3.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: sorry that was an old form. i've updated it and still doesn't work.

Comment: The HTML in your question still looks wrong. Can you post the cost you have so far that is correct?

Comment: The `enctype="multipart/form-data"` goes in your `<form>` tag, not your `<input>` tag.

Comment: It starts uploading. Gets to 99% and then stops. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like there may be size limitations on your server. Have you checked to see what they are?

Comment: I manually add the same file through FTP and it saves. Would that not matter for uploading?

Comment: Yes. FTP isn't subject to the same limits as uploading through PHP.

Comment: I updated the php.ini for max file upload of 50 mb. still no luck. the file is 2 mb.

Comment: Try a few smaller files, getting progressively larger as you go along,  and see what happens.